# How to calculate standard deviation of a distribution when only know z, xi, x_bar and proportion

Tags: distributions

I am wondering how I would calculate the standard deviation of a distribution when the values given are as below:

```
z = -1.08 
xi = 120 
x_bar = 122 
proportion = .14
```

The missing element here is the standard deviation.

z-score:

```
z = (xi - x_bar) / std_dev
```

Using the available data - is there a way to rearrange it to solve for standard deviation?

Using algebra:

```
z = (xi - x_bar) / std_dev

z(std_dev) = (xi - x_bar)
-1.08 * (std_dev) = -2
-1.08 / -1.08 = -2 / -1.08  # divide both sides by z-score
std_dev = 1.85
```

Comment: Yes: use algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Using algebra:

```
z = (xi - x_bar) / std_dev

z(std_dev) = (xi - x_bar)
-1.08 * (std_dev) = -2
-1.08 / -1.08 = -2 / -1.08  # divide both sides by z-score
std_dev = 1.85
```